# GSD Planetscope and RapidEye Images

Tags: planet

PlanetScope basic scene images are 3.7m gsd (nadir) and orthorectified scenes are resampled to 3m per pixel.

How do you improve spatial resolution?

Does this processing affect the characteristics of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John,

The resolution of the ortho products is defined by the product specification, not the actual resolution of the source imagery.  A 3m pixel size was selected because it captures the spatial resolution of Planet's best imagery.  The PSOrthoTile products are actually sampled at 3.125 meters.

So the short answer is we upsample to 3m using gdalwarp's "cubic" resampling kernel (from raw image space) in one step, but there is nothing magical like superresolution happening.